# How to create a new folder in %APPDATA% using C++?

Tags: c++, directory, firemonkey, appdata, c++builder-xe6

I've tried to include the IOUtils library and use the CSIDL command, but it isn't working...

Here is the part of the code that does it:

```
//------------------- Includes -----------------------
#include <fmx.h>
#include <IOUtils.hpp>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
#include "Unit2.h"
#include "Unit3.h"
//---------------------- end  ------------------------
//---- On Form Show (bugged event: It doesn't create the needed folder) ----

void __fastcall TfrmInicio::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (TDirectory::Exists("CSIDL_APPDATA\\Nintersoft\\Ninterfin")) {
        if (FileExists("CSIDL_APPDATA\\Nintersoft\\Ninterfin\\Inf.nf")) {
            mmInfo->Lines->LoadFromFile("CSIDL_APPDATA\\Nintersoft\\Ninterfin\\Inf.nf");
        }
    }
    else {
            TDirectory::CreateDirectory("CSIDL_APPDATA\\Nintersoft\\Ninterfin");
    }
}

//--------------------------------- end ------------------------------------
```

I hope you can helpe me...
Thanks a lot XD

Comment: What sort of error are you getting?

Comment: It just doesn't create the specifyed folder...

Comment: Of course not, because you are not attempting to ask Windows to translate `CSIDL_APPDATA` into a real path.

Comment: Oh, I'm confused now... I've asked before, how to get the %APPDATA% directory in another topic, and other user said that I could use CSIDL_APPDATA or CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA as ROOT of path...

Comment: What the other user said is correct, but you misread his answer. He did not tell you to *literally* put `"CSIDL_..."` in your path string directly. He told you to pass the desired `CSIDL` ID number to `SHGetSpecialFolderPath()`. Read my answer, it shows you how to use a `CSIDL` that way, albeit using `SHGetFolderPath()` instead (which replaces `SHGetSpecialFolderPath()`.

Comment: Ok, now I understood the question, and sorry to trouble you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supposed to hard-code "CSIDL_APPDATA" itself directly into your directory path string.  `CSIDL_APPDATA` is an ID number (specifically, 26) for a virtual folder that you have to resolve dynamically at runtime using the Win32 API, eg:

```
void __fastcall TfrmInicio::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
    WCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH+1] = {0};
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPathW(FmxHandleToHWND(Handle), CSIDL_APPDATA, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, szPath)))
    {
        String DirPath = TPath::Combine(szPath, L"Nintersoft\\Ninterfin");
        TDirectory::CreateDirectory(DirPath);

        String FileName = TPath::Combine(DirPath, L"Inf.nf");
        if (TFile::Exists(FileName))
            mmInfo->Lines->LoadFromFile(FileName);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, on Vista and later only, use `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` instead:

```
void __fastcall TfrmInicio::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
    PWSTR pszPath;
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_RoamingAppData, 0, NULL, &pszPath)))
    { 
        String DirPath = TPath::Combine(pszPath, L"Nintersoft\\Ninterfin");
        CoTaskMemFree(pszPath);

        TDirectory::CreateDirectory(DirPath);

        String FileName = TPath::Combine(DirPath, L"Inf.nf");
        if (TFile::Exists(FileName))
            mmInfo->Lines->LoadFromFile(FileName);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, use `Sysutils::GetEnvironmentVariable()` to retrieve the value of `%APPDATA%` instead of using a `CSIDL` or `KNOWNFOLDERID`:

```
void __fastcall TfrmInicio::FormShow(TObject *Sender)
{
    String DirPath = TPath::Combine(Sysutils::GetEnvironmentVariable(L"APPDATA"), L"Nintersoft\\Ninterfin");
    TDirectory::CreateDirectory(DirPath);

    String FileName = TPath::Combine(DirPath, L"Inf.nf");
    if (TFile::Exists(FileName))
        mmInfo->Lines->LoadFromFile(FileName);
}
```

Comment: Does this code needs a specific library or just with winbase.h it will works? Sorry, I'm learning it slowly, I'm still a newbie with C++

Comment: `SHGetFolderPath()` and `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` are both in `Shell32.dll`, and `GetEnvironmentVariable()` is in the RTL itself and wraps the Win32 version in `kernel32.dll`. The RTL already links to both libraries for you.

Comment: Hello, I'm here just to say that I've changed the latest code to works fine with my program... The first two options I don't know why it doesn't works the C++ builer says: Unknown command, this problems occurs with: SHGetKnownFolderPath; FOLDERID_RoamingAppData; CSIDL_APPDATA and SHGetFolderPathW. Thanks for your support! XD

Comment: You need to add `#include <shlobj.h>` to your code to use those functions.

Comment: Ah ok, was about that when I was asking if is needed to add a different library... So, thanks.

Comment: Remember that the term "library" has a particular meaning in C/C++, so the first thing I thought of was you asking which "import library" was needed.

Answer (score -1):

i think this should help you out (=.

File NewDirectory.cpp

```
//includes standard libraries
#include <iostream>

//includes windows libraries
#include <windows.h>

//includes header files

int NewDirectory(){

    char *Directory = "C://Users/user/AppData/somefolder/";

    //Checks if folder of file exist
    int FilePath = PathFileExist(Directory);

    //Makes new directory
    int NewFolder = CreateDirectory(Directory, NULL);

    if(!FilePath){
        std::cout << "Error could not find folder, trying to create new Directory" << std::endl;

        NewFolder;

        if(!NewFolder){
            std::cout << "Could not make new directory closing" << std::endl;

            return 1;
        } else {
            std::cout << "New Directory" << Directory << "Created!" << std::endl;

            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "the Directory" << Directory << "already exist" << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `CreateDirectory()` fails with an `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` error if the directory already exists. Your example does not handle that case.

Comment: He specifically wants to use the resolution of `%APPDATA%.` This code doesn't comply.

Comment: i hate to tell you this code does comply, it creates a folder within the %appdata% directory, so yeah make sure you know what your talking about before insinuating something is false.

Comment: and @Remy lebeau my code does handle it if a directory exist already, if the directory already exist it outputs the directory is already there.

Comment: @Daniel: this code DOES NOT comply with the user's request, because you hard-coded the entire path instead of using `%APPDATA%` or `CSIDL_APPDATA`.  The actual path may be different on different systems (`C:\Users\<user>\AppData` is not the default on pre-Win7 systems), that is why `%APPDATA%` and `CSIDL_APPDATA` exist. And how many people do you know who have a username of `user`?

Comment: @daniel: Also, your code DOES NOT handle the directory already existing, because `CreateDirectory()` returns 0 on all errors, including `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, so your code would display `"Could not make new directory closing"`. Try it and see for yourself.

Comment: I've seen, I should use that just with console application, isn't it? (because os iostream...) I intent to use it with FireMonkey (Or VCL -> What it works with...) If it works with Firemonkey, thanks. I'm saying that, because I'm still a newbie with C++. Each day I learn a little more XD.

Comment: I've revised this code and yeah, it doesn't works with VCL or FireMonkey. However maybe part of the code is usefull for me, like the directory creation part, so thanks too...

Comment: i didnt fully test the code i was just giving input and making a example reference, and although i have a lot of experience im still learning all there is to know about win32 so @RemyLebeau thanks for your input to, cause as coders we are all learning something new every day.

Comment: @Daniel: Since nothing in your example actually addresses the user's request, you really should delete your answer.